How can one manually trigger Windows' Network Connectivity Status Indicator (NCSI) check
Under windows, I want to determine the Internet connectivity status for both, IPv4 and v6, from a script.
I don't want to use any custom ping solutions, but Windows Network Connectivity Status Indicator (NCSI) service.
I found out that this can be queried like:
powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command '(Get-NetConnectionProfile).IPv4Connectivity; (Get-NetConnectionProfile).IPv6Connectivity'

and will give me e.g.:
Internet
Internet

if both IP versions have connectivity (according to NCSI).
Now the problem is, that Windows seems pretty slow in noticing any change to the connectivity (presumably it checks rather rarely).
So what I'm looking for is a way to tell it, via some scriptable command, to re-check both (v4 and v6) now.
This should work without any hacks like completely stopping&starting any networking or so.
Thanks.

Best way of determining when a TCP connection closes is to use a KeepAlive.  See https://github.com/SammyKrosoft/TCPKeepAlive

@jdweng Not really sure how this is related. My question is about checking whether internet connectivity is established. Keep Alives would require some already existing connection in order to fail or not fail. And even if I'd open some connection so some server, if that fails eventually because of Keep Alives, it may be either because my connectivity is lost, or because the server went down.

Using the keep alive will speed up the status since connection will automatically close when not in use.

@jdweng, it appears that the OP wants to know the status and not keep the connection alive. If it has closed, the OP is not trying to open it back up. Is that right, Philippe?

@lit Indeed. I only want to know whether Windows thinks the Internet is reachable.
